# Docker password store in .docker/config.json

Tags: docker, base64

In `.docker/config.json` I see my password stored as `QA=="`. My password ends with `@`.

```
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.nmlv.nml.com": {
            "auth": "QA==",
            "email": "foo@bar.com"
        }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.4 (darwin)"
    }
}
```

The `auth` property is actually base64 of `username:password` however my password base64 would end with `QAo=`. I am wondering how docker is changing the password?

I used `base64 <<< @` command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you manually base64-encode strings at the command line, you need to be careful to not include a newline.  `echo -n` is helpful for this.

```
$ echo -n '@' | base64
QA==
```

This matches what's in your `.docker/config.json` file.  If I decode your other string

```
$ echo -n 'QAo=' | base64 -D | od -t x1
0000000    40  0a
```

it contains two bytes, ASCII 0x40 (`@`) and 0x0a (newline).